# Relation between fundamental system of neighborhood and basis of topological space

Tags: general-topology, geometry, topological-groups

What is the difference and relation between fundamental system of neighborhood and basis of topological space ?

Definition.

A **base** is a collection $B$ of sets such that every set in the topology can be written as a union of sets in $B$.
If $(X,T)$ is a topological space and $x∈X$ is an element in $X$,a subset $N ⊂X$
is called a neighborhood of $x$ if there exists some open set $D$ such that $x ∈ D⊂ N$. A collection $N$ of neighborhoods of $x$ is called a **fundamental system of neighborhoods** of $x$, if for any neighborhood $M$ of $x$, there exists some neighborhood $N$ in $N$ such
that $x ∈ N ⊂ M$.

**Fundamental system of neighborhood is also called 'basis of point'.**
Their definition is different, but seems like a bit relevant..
What is the relation between them ?

Answer (score 2):

A topological base (basis) is a family $B$ of $open$ sets such that every open set is the union of (some) members of $B$.

The usual terminology is that a local base (basis) at $x$ is a family $B_x$ of $open$ sets, each containing $x$, such that if $u$ is open and $x\in u$ then some $b\in B_x$ satisfies $x\in b\subseteq u.$

A fundamental system of nbhds of $x$ is also called a nbhd-base at $x$. I admit that the terminology could be better.

I prefer "base". When studying various kinds of topological vector spaces we often consider an algebraic or analytic type of "basis" (e.g. Hamel basis, Hilbert-space basis, Schauder basis) while simultaneously considering a topological "base".

Comment: For $x∈X$, we define local basis at $x$ to be $U_x$, then, union of $U_x$ where $x$ runs all $X$ coincidence with the set of openness of the topology defined by this local basis ?

Comment: Union of all the $U_x$ will be a base for the topology of the space.